# Gecko Window doesnot contain a definition of JSContext

Tags: javascript, c#, gecko, geckofx, geckodriver

My Code is it says Gecko Window doesnot contain a definition of JSContext

```js
string outString = "";
using (AutoJSContext js = new AutoJSContext((nsISupports)geckoWebBrowser1.Window.JSContext))
{
js.EvaluateScript(@"window.alert('alert')", out outString);
}
```

Comment: Which version of GeckoFx is it?

Comment: gecko version is 45.0

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the AutoJSContext to evaluate a script. You can try something like the below:

```
myBrowser.Navigate("javascript:void(window.alert('alert'))")
```

See more details here
https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-45.0/issues/37/what-replaces-autojscontext

However, if you're sure that you need the AutoJSContext, then this still works  (Window is `GeckoWindow`):

```
using (AutoJSContext context = new AutoJSContext(this.Browser.Window))
            {
                string result;
                context.EvaluateScript("window.find('',0,0,0,0,1,1)", out result);
            }
```